# Employee contract review in the UK: What's a reasonable price to pay?

Tags: law, employment-law

I'm a techie in the UK and wanted to have my contract reviewed by a lawyer in order to understand specifically what I can and can't do outside of work. For example, whether I could consult on the side for others, start a tech blog and/or pursue my own projects in my spare time. It's not overly clear and I am reluctant to start any projects etc until I know exactly where I stand.

What would you expect to pay for such a service? I've had three quotes ranging from £400 to £1000 (including VAT). The large range in-itself seems odd, I had assume they would be closer together. I think the upper end is a bit steep, but I'm worried that going with the cheapest is a mistake (but all are qualified/vetted lawyers).

Note that I understand that lawyers undergo a lot of training and I'm not looking to knock them! I'm also not after penny pinching and happy to pay a Little over the odds, I just don't want to underpay and get poor service/advice or massively overpay.

So What would you expect to pay for such a service? And do I need to shop around a bit more?